# How to get header button in react native

Tags: react-native, expo, navigationbar

I have created a different class for navigation to maintain the state of loggedIn and loggedOut user as follows:-

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import DrawerContent from "../views/Sidebar"

import Profile from '../views/Profile';
import Extra from '../views/Extra';

import SignIn from '../views/SignIn';

import Home from '../views/Home';
import Info from '../views/Info';
import Logout from '../views/Logout';


export const SignedIn = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Profile: {
        screen: Profile,
    },
    Extra: {
        screen: Extra,
    }
});

export const SignedOut = createStackNavigator({
    SignIn: {
        screen: SignIn,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Sign Up",
            headerRight: <Text>Hi</Text> //calling this gives an error  
        }
    },
});

export const RootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
    return createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            SignedIn: {
                screen: SignedIn,
                navigationOptions: {
                    gesturesEnabled: false
                }
            },
            SignedOut: {
                screen: SignedOut,
                navigationOptions: {
                    gesturesEnabled: false
                }
            }
        }, {
            headerMode: "none",
            mode: "modal",
            initialRouteName: signedIn ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
        }
    );
};
```

I want to create a button in navigation bar on signUp screen but it is giving an error like :- [image: Error here]

header Title is easily shown onto screen but the right and left button doesn't seems to be appear. Any help on this.

Comment: You need to import Text from react native. import { Text } from 'react-native' 

Comment: I have done that still same error ..

Comment: I think you also need to enclose your text with parenthesis :D headerRight: (<Text>Hi</Text>)

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at navigation.js:126

Comment: this warning appear what does that mean and how to resolve it...I am new to react

Comment: This error usually appears when you aren't able to import/export a component. This error could also show when you imported/exported a component wrongly. Based on what you have posted, you weren't able to import Text component from react-native. You could try importing Text first.

Answer (score 1):

Your header button must be a component

The way you are using is not pointing to a valid component

To do that either create a new component 'HeaderRight' and import it like you did for the 'Home' component,then point your headerRight property to it

Like `headerRight:HeaderRight`

Or simply wrap your text element within parenthesis like this

`headerRight:(<Text>Hi</Text>)`

Try and tell me if it is solved

Best regards